# TOPTESI - Missing } inserted when adding line break

Tags: line-breaking, compiling

I'm using the [toptesi](https://ctan.org/pkg/toptesi) template for my master's thesis, I'd like to specify the advisor university but when I add a linebreak `\relatore{advisor 1\\ university1}` I get a compilation error.

```
\documentclass[%
corpo=12pt,
stile=classica,
tipotesi=magistrale,
]{toptesi}


\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9
\blankpagestyle{empty}
\english
\CorsoDiLaureaIn{Master's in}
\TesiDiLaurea{\large Master's Degree Thesis}
\CandidateName{Candidate}% or Candidates
\AdvisorName{Supervisor}% or Supervisors
\CoAdvisorName{Co-supervisor}

\begin{ThesisTitlePage}
\ateneo{Politecnico di Torino}

\titolo{\Large Title}
\corsodilaurea{Computer Engineering}% per la laurea

\relatore{advisor 1\\ university 1}
\secondorelatore{advisor 2}

\sedutadilaurea{\textsc{Academic~year} 2017-2018}% 

\end{ThesisTitlePage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\relatore` field doesn't support multiline output. But you can emulate it by using a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[
  corpo=12pt,
  stile=classica,
  tipotesi=magistrale,
]{toptesi}

\blankpagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\english
\CorsoDiLaureaIn{Master in}
\TesiDiLaurea{Master's Degree Thesis}
\CandidateName{Candidate}% or Candidates
\AdvisorName{Supervisor}% or Supervisors
\CoAdvisorName{Co-supervisor}

\begin{ThesisTitlePage}
\ateneo{Politecnico di Torino}

\titolo{Title}
\corsodilaurea{Computer Engineering}% per la laurea

\relatore{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  advisor 1\\
  university 1\\[1ex]
  \end{tabular}}
\secondorelatore{advisor 2}

\sedutadilaurea{Academic year 2017-2018}

\end{ThesisTitlePage}

\end{document}
```

I've removed the formatting instructions such as `\Large` or `\textsc`. Also I removed the spurious `'s` in `\CorsoDiLaureaIn`.

[image]